# Como Inspecionar um elemento que só aparece quando faço Hover em outro elemento?

Tags: html, css, navegador-de-internet, css-hover, dev-tools

Eu tenho um elemento que ao fazer um `hover` nele vai aparece um *pseudo-elemento* em outro lugar da tela, porém eu gostaria de inspecionar esse *pseudo-elemento* quando ele está visível na tela.

***Como eu faço para inspecionar um elemento que só aparece quando o outro está com `hover`?***

Veja esse exemplo simples

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}
button::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
button:hover::after {
  content: "aqui!";
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Siga os passos:

1. Clique sobre o elemento que você precisa dar o `hover` e inspecione elemento nele.
2. No HTML verifique que este elemento está selecionado e você verá na direita um item `:hov`
3. Clique em `:hov` e selecione `:hover`.

Pronto basta inspecionar o elemento que apareceu na tela e não sai mais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para o **Firefox**, ao invés do botão `:hov` existe o ícone [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] com título "*Toggle pseudo-classes*".

Comment: Criei um GIF com os passos que você citou, acho que fica mais didático que uma imagem estática. Se discordar, pode reverter a edição sem problemas :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss So pelo gif você já merece metade da pontuação :D

Comment: É isso mesmo, Obrigado!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss excelente edição! Ficou muito bom e didático para todos consultarem vlw!